# Unable to read $ in .properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing, spring-cloud-feign

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
        classes = {
                FeignAutoConfiguration.class,
                HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class,
                AbcClientConfiguration.class,
                ObjectMapper.class
        },
        properties = {
                "downstream.abc.api.apiHost=https://staging.abc.com",
                "downstream.abc.api.xPartnerAcessKeyValue=abcdefg",
                "downstream.abc.api.partnerId=123",
                "downstream.abc.api.query=mutation raasDeleteCustomerPii($input: RaasDeleteCustomerPiiInput!) { raasDeleteCustomerPii(input: $input) {success}}"
        }
)
@EnableFeignClients(clients = {
        AbcApiClient.class
})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AbcApiProperties.class)
```

Unable to read $ in $input while parsing ${downstream.abc.api.query} . I am unable to use \ or ` for escape.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new variable that has the value of $ like that:

```
public static final char dollar = '$';
```

then in your annotation do a simple concatenation as follow:

```
"downstream.abc.api.query=mutation raasDeleteCustomerPii("+dollar+"input: RaasDeleteCustomerPiiInput!) { raasDeleteCustomerPii(input: $input) {success}}"
```